# Why is this spatial query returning empty?

Tags: spatial-query

Using the simple table below, I'm trying to select the 'latlng POINT' that is within the POLYGON given. But the return is always empty, what am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE mypoi (
   id int not null auto_increment,
  latlng POINT not null,
  primary key(id)
)ENGINE=MyISM;

INSERT INTO mypoi VALUES
(1 ,  POINT( 39.274, -94.4233  )),
(2 , POINT( 39.5, -94.3483  ));

SELECT id, x(latlng), y(latlng)
FROM mypoi
WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON((39.48025, -94.73566 , 39.48025, -94.09021 , 39.09122, -94.09021 , 39.09122, -94.73566))'),latlng);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) polygons are closed by including the original point at the end of the sequence of points. They also have each point separated by a comma (i.e. `x1 y1, x2 y2, ..., x1 y1`). There are just some formatting issues in the polygon text.

```
SELECT id, x(latlng), y(latlng)
FROM mypoi
WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON((39.48025 -94.73566, 39.48025 -94.09021, 39.09122 -94.09021, 39.09122 -94.73566, 39.48025 -94.73566))'),latlng);
```

Comment: @Thomas_Portwood So the final point in the () is also the first point? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Yep! I ran your exact code to make sure I'm not lying to you. Were you able to try it?

Comment: Yes, I still have some things to work out but what you said proved good.

Comment: @Thomas_Portwood In my production environment the where clause looks like this; WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 40.4402763 -95.377758, 40.4402763 -91.750869, 37.9574921 -91.750869, 37.9574921 -95.377758, 40.4402763 -95.377758 ))'),latlng); No error when it runs but nothing is returned and there should be quite a few rows selected. Any thoughts, anything specific I should be looking at?

Comment: Hm .. it is probably best to create a separate question with a few more specifics, such as a selection of the top 10 or 20 points from the mypoi table, your db version, etc. with appropriate tags on the question. Adding all the necessary info in comments is going to be hard. I am happy to dive in and see if I can help.